# Issue with jsPDF: Uncaught (in Promise) Error: Could not load dompurify: Error: cannot find module 'dompurify'

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using npm and parcel to build a web app. the dist files get copied to an apache2 server, (so not running under the node server) and when trying to generate a PDF using jsPDF I' getting this error:

Uncaught (in Promise) Error: Could not load dompurify: Error: cannot find module 'dompurify'

I think this is a problem with "sPDF will then dynamically load them (ie: dompurify and html2canvas) when required (using the respective module format, e.g. dynamic imports)." but I don't know how to work around it.

I have installed:
npm install --save jspdf dompurify html2canvas

in my JS I "import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

```
    // download PDF doc
    let filename = 'pdf-' + $('#fh-date').val() + '-'
        + $('#fh-num').val() + '.pdf';
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    doc.html($('#fh-tmp').html(), {
        'width': 100, // max width of content of PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save(filename);
        },
    });
```

How do I solve this issue. Thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran accross this problem in my vue project, which i fixed by updating with "npm update".

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and see if that resolves the issue for me. I ended up moving this PDF generation to the server to simplify it and avoid the Same Origin issues that were tainting the canvas, but I have other pages that I would still like to generate in the browser so hopefully this solve the problem for them.